# DateTimeOffset Missing Now Property in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
$date = New-Object System.DateTimeOffset
$date
```

Output:

```
DateTime      : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
UtcDateTime   : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
LocalDateTime : 1/1/0001 11:00:00 AM
Date          : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Day           : 1
DayOfWeek     : Monday
DayOfYear     : 1
Hour          : 0
Millisecond   : 0
Minute        : 0
Month         : 1
Offset        : 00:00:00
Second        : 0
Ticks         : 0
UtcTicks      : 0
TimeOfDay     : 00:00:00
Year          : 1
```

If Powershell is based on .NET, why is there no Now property for the DateTimeOffset object?
In C# I can access it, but not in Powershell. I am using Powershell 4.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Now` is a static member, not an instance member.

```
[System.DateTimeOffset]::Now;
```

[MSDN docs for DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)